# Minicart and account nav block_html cache is not updating as needed

Tags: magento-1.14.3.3

I have full page cache disabled as I troubleshoot this issue.

My minicart and account nav lives within my header (header.phtml). As I add items to cart, log in, and log out the navigation and minicart remain cached -- the content does not update.

I've tried setting cache lifetime, manipulating the cache key, yet the block is always cached.

Here is my local.xml

```
    <reference name="header">
        <!--block type="directory/currency" name="currency" as="currency_switcher" template="page/switch/currency.phtml"/-->
        <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
        <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/template" template="page/html/accountmenu.phtml" name="account_menu"/>
        <block type="core/template" template="page/html/customergreeting.phtml" name="customer_greeting">
            <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>
        </block>
        <block type="checkout/cart_minicart" name="minicart_head" template="checkout/cart/minicart.phtml" before="-">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="minicart_content" template="checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender">
                    <type>default</type>
                    <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block>
                    <template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <action method="addItemRender">
                    <type>simple</type>
                    <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block>
                    <template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <action method="addItemRender">
                    <type>grouped</type>
                    <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block>
                    <template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <action method="addItemRender">
                    <type>configurable</type>
                    <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block>
                    <template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.cart_promotion" as="cart_promotion" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Mini-cart promotion block</label>
                </block>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
            <label>Navigation Bar</label>
            <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml">
                <block type="contentmanager/menu" name="main-menu" alias="americas.menu"/>
                <block type="contentmanager/menu" name="main-menu-fr_ca"  alias="americas.french.menu"/>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml">
                    <block type="themecustom/menu_image" name="menu.image.container" as="image_container" template="page/html/topmenu/image.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="searchresults/form_mini" name="mobile.search" as="topSearchMobile" template="catalogsearch/form.mobile.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```